# Timestamp Array

Tags: php, datetime

I need a little help with this bit.  I am trying to figure out how do this using an array.  There are 8 different areas using the time stamp.  The ID for each of the aareas are TS - TS8. I need it where when I update the time, it will update all areas.  Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setEffectiveDate() {
    document.getElementById("ts").effdte.value = '<?php echo("As of: " . date('d F, Y') . " 12:10 AM ET") ?>';
    for (i=2; i<=6; i++)
        document.getElementById("ts" + i).effdte.value = '<?php echo("As of: " . date('d F, Y') . " 12:10 AM ET") ?>';
}
</script>
```

Thanks for the resposnse!  setEffectiveDate is being called as `<body onLoad="setEffectiveDate();">` and "effdte" is as follows

```
<form name="ts" id="ts">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="650" id="effective_date">
    <tr>
     <td><input id="effdte" type="text" name="effdte" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing server-side with client-side scripting. If you parse this function, PHP will add the timestamp of the time when the page is loaded into the function. Thus, everytime you call this function the same timestamp is being loaded.

I'm not sure what you are trying to load, I guess there's a part missing in this code (f.e. what part of your page is calling the setEffectiveDate() function?

Also I'm not sure what 'effdte' is in your document.getElementByID() part..